# Create and Retrive django session objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

*I have customised the django default user table and used it for user signup and login.* Now I need to create django session object to create a shopping cart (like that of an ecommerce website) which is user specific.**How to create and retrive session objects in django??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides full and built-in support for sessions (also anonymous sessions). First thing you need to enable the middleware session in the settings. Then you can easily retrieve the session as a dict in the views calling the request param at any point in your view.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Get a param:
    my_param = request.session.get('my_param'):
    # Set a param:
    request.session['my_param'] = True
    # Some logic here ...
    return HttpResponse('...')
```

Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)